# Threading lambda functions

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, pthreads

I've created this very small header that allows direct creation of threads from lambdas.
I can't find anything else similar on the net so I want to know whether there are any problems with this that I have not thought of. It is based on [tinythread++](http://tinythreadpp.bitsnbites.eu/), but can easily be altered to work with pthread or other threading libraries that can take a `void (void*)` (or `void* (void*)`) function and a `void*` argument for the function to start a thread. Note that this implementation is assuming limited C++0x/11 support, i.e. just lambdas.

```
#include "tinythread.h"

namespace lthread {
    /// implementation details - do not use directly
    namespace impl {
        template<typename Func>
        void use_function_once(void* _f) {
            const Func* f = (const Func*)_f;
            (*f)();
            delete f; // delete - no longer needed
        }
        template<typename Func>
        void use_function(void* _f) {
            const Func* f = (const Func*)_f;
            (*f)();
        }
    }

    /// Creates a thread based on a temporary function.
    /// Copies the function onto the heap for use outside of the local scope, removes from the heap when finished.
    template<typename Func>
    tthread::thread* new_thread(const Func& f) {
        Func* _f = new Func(f); // copy to heap
        return new tthread::thread(&impl::use_function_once<Func>,(void*)_f);
    }

    /// Creates a thread based on a guaranteed persistent function.
    /// Does not copy or delete the function.
    template<typename Func>
    tthread::thread* new_thread(const Func* f) {
        return new tthread::thread(&impl::use_function<Func>, (void*)f);
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
size_t a = 1;
size_t b = 0;
tthread::thread* t = lthread::new_thread([&] () {
    std::cout << "I'm in a thread!\n";
    std::cout << "'a' is " << a << std::endl;
    b = 1;
});
t->join();
std::cout << "'b' is " << b << std::endl;
delete t;
```

Comment: What if `(*f)();` should throw? You get a leak.

Comment: @user1095108 Good point.

Answer (score 1):

1. surely you can just use `std::function<void()>` instead of templating on the function type?
2. capturing by reference can go horribly wrong. It's not a bug in your library, just an observation ...

   ```
   tthread::thread* startthread(size_t a, size_t b)
   {
       return lthread::new_thread([&] ()
           {
               std::cout << "I'm in a thread!\n";
               std::cout << "'a' is " << a << std::endl;
               b = 1;
           }
           );
   }

   int main()
   {
       tthread::thread *t = startthread(1,2);
       t->join();
       delete t;
   }
   ```
3. `use_function_once` is vulnerable to the function call throwing an exception: you should probably assign it to a smart pointer before calling, and lose the explicit delete.
4. that overload of `new_thread` also has a problem if either `new` or `tthread::thread` can throw: it will leak the heap-allocated Func. You can fix this with a smart pointer too.

Comment: I have already made a change to the code - the two `new_thread` functions now have different names - the by reference version was capturing the pointer argument instead of the pointer version and thus didn't compile as intended.

Comment: Also, I am fully aware of the point you are making with that snippet, but that also applies to any other deferred running of a lambda function. Users should be aware of this as when using by-reference lambdas in other situations.